# How do I do some minor conversions while importing a chat log into Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, import

I exported a chat log as a comma delimited CSV.  From that file, I'm trying to import and format it in Excel.
The file has a field for Date and Time formatted mostly as `YYYY.MM.DD HH:MM:SS` with some oddballs as `dd month YYYY HH:MM:SS`, and the few oddballs can be easily changed manually before processing into Excel.

Importing this file into Excel, how do I split the field into two separate columns?  I'd like one for date, one for time, each in formats which Excel would recognize as dates and times. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in column **A,** in **B1** enter:

=DATE(MID(A1,1,4),MID(A1,6,2),MID(A1,9,2))

and copy down

In **C1** enter:

```
=TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,8))
```

and copy down

For example:

[image]

Comment: I was going to moan about how this means I can't delete the original column afterwards, but I quickly realise I could just hide the column. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Turns out that all the values in the original data had a 'space' at the end, which I didn't originally realise. Whilst your formula was correct for the information I'd given, it was incorrect for what I actually had. The first digit of the time was lost in all the cells. (I spotted this after I Copied and Special Pasted into absolute values and removed the original column). Thankfully, I had a backup. Solved the problem but that was a close call.

Comment: @JayNicholasTurner.....Good Job! ......you can see that **removing** the original data is risky....it is better to hide the column.

Comment: I went ahead and created a backup in a .7z file before I removed the original data just so I can fix any hiccups if need be.